# Cryptic Node Tick Result -- CPU Taking 100%

Tags: node.js, socket.io, profiling

So ive run into a slight snag with an application that I am writing. The application is a simple relay server, using Socket.IO and Node. Everything works great, but when it gets under heavy load, the process spikes to 100% CPU and stays there.

I ran a node-tick on it, and this is what the result was

```js
Statistical profiling result from v8.log, (83336 ticks, 0 unaccounted, 0 excluded).

 [Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
  83220   99.9%    0.0%  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
     97    0.1%    0.0%  /usr/bin/nodejs
      9    0.0%    0.0%  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so

 [JavaScript]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
      1    0.0%   10.0%  Stub: FastNewClosureStub
      1    0.0%   10.0%  Stub: CallConstructStub_Recording
      1    0.0%   10.0%  LazyCompile: ~stringify native json.js:308
      1    0.0%   10.0%  LazyCompile: ~hash /opt/connect/node/node_modules/sticky-session/lib/sticky-session.js:4
      1    0.0%   10.0%  LazyCompile: ~exports.dirname path.js:415
      1    0.0%   10.0%  LazyCompile: ~buildFn /opt/connect/node/node_modules/socket.io-redis/node_modules/msgpack-js/node_modules/bops/read.js:5
      1    0.0%   10.0%  LazyCompile: ~addListener events.js:126
      1    0.0%   10.0%  LazyCompile: ~ToObject native runtime.js:567
      1    0.0%   10.0%  LazyCompile: *setTime native date.js:482
      1    0.0%   10.0%  LazyCompile: *DefineOneShotAccessor native messages.js:767

 [C++]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name

 [GC]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
      3    0.0%

 [Bottom up (heavy) profile]:
  Note: percentage shows a share of a particular caller in the total
  amount of its parent calls.
  Callers occupying less than 2.0% are not shown.

   ticks parent  name
  83220   99.9%  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so


 [Top down (heavy) profile]:
  Note: callees occupying less than 0.1% are not shown.

  inclusive      self           name
  ticks   total  ticks   total
  83192   99.8%  83192   99.8%  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so

    114    0.1%      0    0.0%  Function: ~<anonymous> node.js:27
    113    0.1%      0    0.0%    LazyCompile: ~startup node.js:30
    103    0.1%      0    0.0%      LazyCompile: ~Module.runMain module.js:495
     98    0.1%      0    0.0%        LazyCompile: Module._load module.js:275
     90    0.1%      0    0.0%          LazyCompile: ~Module.load module.js:346
     89    0.1%      0    0.0%            LazyCompile: ~Module._extensions..js module.js:472
     88    0.1%      0    0.0%              LazyCompile: ~Module._compile module.js:374
     88    0.1%      0    0.0%                Function: ~<anonymous> /opt/connect/node/lib/connect.js:1
```

**83220   99.9%    0.0%  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so**

Only 1 library seems to be the problem -- but I can figure out what the heck it is for. My hunch is the json processing im doing -- but I can be sure.

Has anyone run into this problem before?